# Where's the standard python exception list for programmes to raise?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

There is a list [standard python exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy) that we should watch out, but I don't think these are the ones we should raise ourselves, cause they are rarely applicable.

I'm curious if there exists a list within standard python library, with exceptions similar to .NET's [ApplicationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx), [ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception.aspx), [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx), [InvalidOperationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) — exceptions that we can raise ourselves?

Or is there different, more pythonic way to handle common error cases, than raising standard exceptions?

EDIT: I'm not asking on how to handle exceptions but what types I can and should raise where needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the error matches the description of one of the standard python exception classes, then by all means throw it.

Common ones to use are `TypeError` and `ValueError`, the list you linked to already is the standard list.

If you want to have application specific ones, then subclassing Exception or one of it's descendants is the way to go.

To reference the examples you gave from .NET
`ApplicationException` is closest to `RuntimeError`
`ArgumentNullException` will probably be an `AttributeError` (try and call the method you want, let python raise the exception a la duck typing)
`AttributeOutOfRange` is just a more specific `ValueError`
`InvalidOperationException` could be any number of roughly equivalent exceptions form the python standard lib.

Basically, pick one that reflects whatever error it is you're raising based on the descriptions from the http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html page.

Comment: Probably `ValueError` would fill most my needs. Thx, I did miss it while skimming through the list!

Answer (score 14):

First, Python raises standard exceptions for you.

> It's better to ask forgiveness than to ask permission

Simply attempt the operation and let Python raise the exception.  Don't bracket everything with `if would_not_work(): raise Exception`.  Never worth writing.  Python already does this in **all** cases.

If you think you need to raise a standard exception, you're probably writing too much code.

You may have to raise `ValueError`.

```
def someFunction( arg1 ):
    if arg1 <= 0.0:
        raise ValueError( "Guess Again." )
```

Once in a while, you might need to raise a `TypeError`, but it's rare.

```
def someFunctionWithConstraints( arg1 ):
    if isinstance(arg1,float):
         raise TypeError( "Can't work with float and can't convert to int, either" )
    etc.
```

Second, you almost always want to create your own, unique exceptions.

```
 class MyException( Exception ): 
     pass
```

That's all it takes to create something distinctive and unique to your application.

Comment: This guy is against the idea of creating extra exceptions in Python - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0

Answer (score 5):

I seem to recall being trained by the documentation that it is ok to raise predefined exceptions, as long as they are appropriate.  For example, the recommended way to terminate is no longer to call exit() but rather to raise SystemExit.

Another example given is to reuse the IndexError exception on custom container types.

Of course, your application should define its own exceptions rather than to actually repurpose system exceptions.  I'm just saying there's no prohibition from reusing them where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic way is just let the exceptions pass through from Python itself. For example, instead of:

```
def foo(arg):
  if arg is None:
    raise SomeNoneException
  bar = arg.param
```

Just do:

```
def foo(arg):
  bar = arg.param
```

If `arg` is `None` or doesn't have the `param` attribute, you will get an exception from Python itself.

In the Python [glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html) this is called "EAFP":

> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding
>   style assumes the existence of valid
>   keys or attributes and catches
>   exceptions if the assumption proves
>   false. This clean and fast style is
>   characterized by the presence of many
>   try and except statements. The
>   technique contrasts with the LBYL (Look Before You Leap)
>   style common to many other languages
>   such as C.

And it works well in tandem with Python's inherent duck typing philosophy.

---

This doesn't mean you should not create exceptions of your own, of course, just that you don't need to wrap the already existing Python exceptions.

For your own exceptions, create classes deriving from `Exception` and throw them when it's suitable.

Comment: This `arg.param` thechnique, is it just checking if `arg` is an instance of an object that have a field `param`?

Comment: @WooYek: indeed, you expect `arg` to be such an object, so don't check for it explicitly, just access `arg.param` and Python will throw an error if it's not there.